# Interactions with time-dependent covariates in survival analysis

Tags: data-visualization, survival, time-varying-covariate

I am new to R and I just wanted to know if it is possible to test an interaction between a time-varying covariate and a time-invariant covariate in survival analysis?

A related question is, can you plot the time-dependent covariate effect on survival for different groups?

Thanks!

```
coxph4b <- coxph(Surv(start, stop, frust_event) ~ avoid + newSDQtgr + avoid:newSDQtgr + frailty(id),
                 ties = c ("efron"),
                 data = frustrec2a)
summary(coxph4b)
frust.surv<-survfit(coxph4b)
frust.surv <- survfit(Surv(second, frust_event) ~ avoid:newSDQtgr, data = frustrec2)
plot(frust.surv, lty = 2:3)
legend(100, .9, c("avoid", "no avoid"), lty = 2:3)
title("Kaplan-Meier Curves for children's recurring aggression")
lsurv2 <- survfit(Surv(second, frust_event) ~ avoid*newSDQtgr, frustrec2, type='fleming')
plot(lsurv2, lty=2:3, fun="cumhaz",
     xlab="Seconds", ylab="Cumulative Hazard")
```

Comment: There is a frailty term in the model. What does that represent? Is this a repeated-events model perhaps? The `coxme` package is now preferred over a `coxph` frailty term for mixed-effects Cox models, if that's what you really need.

Comment: @EdM Yes, this is a repeated-events model. Does that change the way I use the survfit function?

Comment: `survfit` certainly handles repeated events with cumulative hazards; see Section 2.2 of the main vignette in the `survival` package. Work on specifying a proper `newdata` data frame for the conditions you wish to plot, as noted in my comments below my answer. Also, please add _to the question_ information about the predictors; `avoid` seems to be a 2-level factor, but what type of data is `newSDQtgr` and which of them might be time-varying?

Comment: @EdM avoid is the time-dependent covariate (0 = occurs, 1 = does not occur) on each second of the task. newSDQtgr is a grouping variable for 0= low problems and 1= high problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Survival analysis is performed at event times. What matters *at each event time* in a Cox proportional hazards regression is the set of *current* values of covariates for the case that had the event, versus *current* covariate values for those still at risk who didn't have the event.

A regression coefficient and interaction terms involving a time-varying covariate are thus no different from those for a time-invariant covariate. The regression coefficients and associated hazard ratios are still constant over time. That means that the effect on survival associated with any *particular value* of the time-varying covariate is constant over time. All that differs is that the values of the time-varying covariates can vary with time.

Once you have a model you certainly can plot predicted survival for members of any particular groups or combinations of covariate values, and you can even allow for time-varying values of covariates in the new data that you provide to the model if you format the data properly. This can be done, for example, with the `survfit.coxph()` function in the R `survival` package. The help page includes the following critical warning, however:

> ... although predictions with a time-dependent covariate path can be useful, it is very easy to create a prediction that is senseless. Users are encouraged to seek out a text that discusses the issue in detail.

Things are more complicated if you are considering time-varying *coefficients* for covariates. The [time-dependent vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) provided with the `survival` package is an introduction to issues with respect to time-dependent covariates and coefficients.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help.  I seem to run into an issue with the survfit.coxph() function though when I try to make an interaction term with the time-varying covariate and the time-invariant covariate. R produces this error:                                                                                        
  Error in survfit.formula(Surv(second, frust_event) ~ avoid * newSDQtgr,  : 
  Interaction terms are not valid for this function.

Comment: @D.Ade just to check: did you first run `coxph()` to get a `coxph.object` describing your model, design a `newdata` data frame (following the highly detailed instructions for time-dependent covariates on the `survfit.coxph` manual page) to describe the conditions for which you want to generate the plot, and then submit that `coxph.object` and the `newdata` to `survfit()`?

Comment: Yes I feel like I followed the right path to get the coxph.object. I've updated my original question with the code I was following. Have I done something wrong here?

Comment: thanks for editing the code, is it now correct? I still get the error in R.

Comment: @D.Ade you need to specify a `newdata` data frame that contains the sets of covariate values for which you want to generate the plots, e.g. specific values of `avoid` and `newSDQtgr`, potentially over time. I don't see that in your code. The manual page for `survfit.coxph` has very explicit instructions on how to set up that data frame when there are time-dependent covariates. Then you call `survfit(coxph4b,newdata)` to get a `survfit` object that you can summarize and plot as desired.